# Dash Python by plot.ly callbacks, and Attributes and Properties in web applications

Tags: callback, plotly-dash

In Dash, by Plotly helping section in Callbacks https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing it is stated that:

> Dash components are described declaratively by a set of attributes. All of these attributes can be updated by callback functions

Using the definition of [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html):

- **Attributes**: Attributes are defined by HTML. They initialize DOM properties and then they are done.
- **Properties**: Properties are defined by the DOM (Document Object Model). After DOM has been fully initialized these properties can change.

It is logic and reasonable to say that Dash Callbacks retrieve a specific DOM object by its id, and 'read' its property (not the HTML attribute that initialized it). Example: it is possible to have an Input Callback listening to a graph figure 'hoverData' change property.

If this assumption is true:

**So basically dash Callbacks operate after the DOM has been initialized, also again they operate on DOM properties not HTML attributes.**

So again if true case this could be clearly stated in documentation which would improve to avoid developers confusing this sometimes not very obvious terms.

Comment: Is this a question or a comment about a documentation of dash?

Comment: question but i have found the answer, dash callbacks work with DOM Properties not HTML attributes so i will add answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found an answer, dash callbacks work with DOM Properties which is more accurate than saying HTML attributes.